# Subclassing viewconroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, viewcontroller

I create view controller from  storyboard with code

```
    ListsViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:kListsViewController];
```

I created subclass of it, but the code from this subclass did not executed. I put in in viewDidLoad.

How can I subclass it?
I need to create it strictly with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:

Comment: It would help if you show more code, please show what you are doing, otherwise, it's tough to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

> the code from this subclass did not executed. I put in in viewDidLoad

View controllers load their views lazily, i.e. not until they are needed. Creating a view controller, as you do here:

```
ListsViewController *viewController =
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:kListsViewController];
```

...does not cause the view controller's view to load. That is why its `viewDidLoad` is not executing.